# If faith releases from the obligation of laws, why wasn't the relationship between God and Abraham a lawless one?

Tags: law

Genesis 26:5 New International Version

> because Abraham obeyed me and did everything I required of him, keeping my commands, my decrees and my instructions.”

Romans 4:11 New International Version

> And he received circumcision as a sign, a seal of the righteousness that he had by faith while he was still uncircumcised. So then, he is the father of all who believe but have not been circumcised, in order that righteousness might be credited to them.

Romans 10:4 New International Version

> Christ is the culmination of the law so that there may be righteousness for everyone who believes.

If faith releases from the obligation of laws, why wasn't the relationship between God and Abraham a lawless one?

Comment: As this Q depends on the idea that "faith releases from the obligation of laws", it is necessary to first provide biblical proof that that is the case. Only then can answers be forthcoming. But if the premise is unfounded, then the Q will have to be completely rephrased.

Comment: There is rarely greater obedience seen than Abraham's obedience in offering up his own son, at God's request. What a slander to call Abraham's relationship with God 'lawless'. It was not bondage to the legal precept, No. But it was by no means 'lawless'.

Comment: lack of law, what would be the best translation? I used "lawless"

Comment: 'Without law' and 'apart from law' (in the New Testament expression of justification by faith) are not at all the same as 'lawless'. 'Lawless' is behaviour that disregards law. Justification 'without law' and 'apart from law' honours the law, yet justifies by grace without law.

Answer (score 1):

Faith does not release a person from the obligation of the laws.  It releases one from the penalty of the Mosaic Law and sin, not the penalty of civil law.

> What shall we say then? Are we to continue in sin that grace may abound?  By no means! How can we who died to sin still live in it?
> (Rom. 6:1–2, ESV)

> What then? Are we to sin because we are not under law but under grace? By no means! Do you not know that if you present yourselves to anyone as obedient slaves, you are slaves of the one whom you obey, either of sin, which leads to death, or of obedience, which leads to righteousness?  But thanks be to God, that you who were once slaves of sin have become obedient from the heart to the standard of teaching to which you were committed, and, having been set free from sin, have become slaves of righteousness.
> (Rom. 6:15–18, ESV)

> Let every person be subject to the governing authorities. For there is no authority except from God, and those that exist have been instituted by God.
> (Rom. 13:1, ESV)

**Examples of Obligation**

> Owe no one anything, except to love each other, for the one who loves another has fulfilled the law...
> (Rom. 13:8, ESV)

> A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another: just as I have loved you, you also are to love one another.  By this all people will know that you are my disciples, if you have love for one another.”
> (John 13:34–35, ESV)

Consider Luke 10:25-37; James 1:26-27

Comment: All relationships are governed by rules of some sort, whether marriages, friendships, servants-master, mother-daughter, etc. +1.